# The < operator can not be applied to instances of type int and int

Tags: android

Good daytime! I have a trouble with AIDE on my tablet. Here is an error of the following contents: "The `<` operator can not be applied to instances of type `int` and `int`".
Here's that part of code:

```
msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);  
    etc...
```

What's wrong in it - I don't understand! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++)
```

Also it could be a compile problem so clean your project

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a simple problem with the way the code is written.
Some crucial information that you should include in your question is what is suggested for QuickFix options.
I would try some simple solutions like parentheses:

```
for (int i=0; i<(msgs.length); i++) {
```

Please include in a comment whether it worked or not and some QuickFix Options.

Comment: Unfortunately, There's no QuickFix suggestions in AIDE. Your suggestion to use '(' gives the same result. It emphasizes with the red line "i<(msgs.length);"...

Comment: Maybe you should try declaring msgs.length in a variable and then insert the variable there instead.

Comment: Have a new problem: I try to create new project in AIDE, but there is a new error "Git create failed: aux". And after that, in empty app, in error-window, there is a message: This method must return a value of type ". And emphasizes penultimate bracket. What is wants??? I am suppressed...